# break using while

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to do a break from the second while , not from the first while ?

```
declare @i int, @j int
select @i = 0, @j = 0
while @i < 3 begin ---first while  
    while @j < 3 begin
        select @i as i, @j as j ---second while  
        set @j = @j + 1
        break 
    end
    set @i = @i + 1
 set @j = 0
end
```

Comment: By far the best approach would be to reconsider this approach. Looping is horribly inefficient and can almost always be rewritten using a set based approach.

Comment: What the question actually? You're already doing a break from the second while no?

Answer (score 0):

Your code, as it is written, does break out from the second while (inner loop) on SQL Server 2014.

1. Sets i and j to 0
2. Enters outer loop
3. Enters inner loop
4. Expresses i and j (0, 0)
5. Increments j (now 1)
6. Breaks out of inner loop
7. Increments i (now 1) in outer loop
8. Enters inner loop again (because it didn't break out of outer loop)
9. Expresses i and j (1, 1)
10. Increments j (now 2)
11. Breaks out of inner loop
12. Increments i (now 2) in outer loop
13. Enters inner loop and expresses i and j (2, 2)
14. Increments j (now 3)
15. Breaks out of inner loop
16. Increment i (now 3)
17. Hits exit condition on outer loop because @i is not less then 3
18. Exits

Is this what you expected?  What version of SQL Server are you using?  (I believe they should all be the same in this regard)